# With doctrine I am not able to get the right sequence name for Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, sequence

When I try to insert a new entity in my Postgres database using doctrine I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "schema.table_id_seq" does not exist
```

Or in my database the sequence is called "schema.seq_table_id"

As we can see in the file Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory, the sequence name is set like:

```
$sequenceName   = $class->getTableName() . '_' . $columnName . '_seq';
```

Is there anyway to specify the sequence otherwise in order to have "seq" as prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like your entity has been defined with the wrong sequence name.  You can specify what the sequence name is with annotations in your entity class like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class MyTable
{
    /**
     * @var integer $tableId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="table_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="schema.seq_table_id", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $tableId;

    // ......
```

So it doesn't matter what your sequence name is, you can specify it like that.  If I understood your question properly, this should fix the problem